# Pass only specific dates from array into function

Tags: matlab

This is my code

```
 for i= 1:length(t)
    h(i)=t(i)
    if % condition here??
        myfunction(h)        
    end 
end
```

t is a date array like:

```
   2009-05-07
   2010-05-09
   2011-05-16
   2012-05-21
   2014-05-24
   2016-05-27
   2016-05-31
```

I want to make an if test or something that makes dates before 2011 not go into the function.

Comment: are your dates strings or [datetime](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `t` is in *datetime* format, you can use the `year` property:

```
for ii = 1:length(t)
    h = t(ii);
    if year(h) >= 2011
        myfunction(h);      
    end 
end
```

You can shorten the loop by testing all of the dates at once, this will be *much* quicker than doing an `if` check for every date:

```
t_after2011 = t(year(t) >= 2011);
for ii = 1:length(t_after2011)
    myfunction(t_after2011(ii));
end
```

---

If it is a cell array of strings, you can convert it to datetime first using `t_datetime = datetime(t);`

Answer (score 0):

Convert your dates to date vectors using *datevec*. Now you can access the years from this vectors and put your condition.

```
str = {'2009-05-07'
   '2010-05-09'
   '2011-05-16'
   '2012-05-21'
   '2014-05-24'
   '2016-05-27'
   '2016-05-31'} ;
vec = datevec(str) ;

for i = 1:size(str,1)

    if vec(i,1)>2011
        disp(str{i}) ;
    end
end
```